# Cant create Bibliography "Undefined control sequenze..."

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

I need help for my bibliography. After basically watching every toturial and doing everything to create the references i still cant get behind this error.

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength\headheight{16pt}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[small]{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{HTWK-Leipzig}
\rhead{Lxe}
\author{Lxe}
\title{Bachelor}
\date{04.05.2021}
\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}

\maketitle
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{Preamble}

\subsection{Personal motivation}

Its ... \cite{waziri2013properties}... lack facilities for testing and technology for computing. With the following discoveries a manual on how to create a strong brick with simple methods and high economical beneﬁt should be deducible.
\subsection{Structure}
First of all the ... masonry bricks.
\section{Abstract}
\pagebreak

\section{Construction methods in third world countries, current state of art}
\subsection{Range of materials}
The ... the ﬁre alive are constantly exposed to the smoke. Experiences have shown that unless its done in huge quantities in the right facility its not worth it compared to concrete or mud bricks.
\end{doublespace}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

The bib file looks like this:

```
@article{waziri2013properties,
  title={Properties of compressed stabilized earth blocks (CSEB) for low-cost housing construction: a preliminary investigation},
  author={Waziri, Baba Shehu and Lawan, Zanna Alhaji and others},
  year={2013}
}

@article{rigassi1985compressed,
  title={Compressed earth blocks: Manual of production},
  author={Rigassi, Vincent and others},
  year={1985},
}

@article{deboucha2011review,
  title={A review on bricks and stabilized compressed earth blocks},
  author={Deboucha, Sadek and Hashim, Roslan},
  year={2011}
}

@article{MOSTAFA201653,
title = {Experimental analysis of Compressed Earth Block (CEB) with banana fibers resisting flexural and compression forces},
year = {2016},
}
```

Comment: Welcome. You may delete `.bib` of your bibliography file and add a package for the bibliography like `natbib` or `biblatex`

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the APA stuff but I'd say that using the `apacite` bibliography style requires also the `apacite` package.

Comment: I just used apacite package, that fixed it, thank you really much. I previously used "fancy" and forgot that i also didnt use package for that (only in pagestyle) maybe its not even a bibliography style i dont know, but it definetly made my day, thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was failure to load a necessary package, identified in the comments.